# Case tags and IF / Else Statements in Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
Case When [Days to Term]=>0 Then "[Days to Term]" ELSE "[Start Date to Current Date]" End
```

There are some data in columns "Days to Term" and "Start Date to Current Date".

The premise is to conditionally return the value from the column "Days to Term" if the value is greater than 0.

If the value is 0 (meaning the candidate has not been terminated) the Else statement is to show the value of "Start Date to Current Date". This column was created using sysdate-StartActivity.Startdate.

I've never used If, Else or Elseif statements in Oracle before. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Oracle allows case expressions, so what you're doing looks roughly right as pseudocode, except you have `>=0` instead of `>0`. Presumably you're replacing the bits in square brackets with your real column names, or a calculation in the `else` part. It would be helpful to edit your question to include your table structure and sample data, the results you are trying to see, your best attempt at a query and what was wrong with it (errors, wrong result).

Comment: @AlexPoole - it is even worse than that. The OP does not have `>=` but `=>`, which will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Case When [Days to Term] > 0 THEN [Days to Term] ELSE [Start Date to Current Date] End

This is what I ended up with - and it's working for now.